# Extracting multiple photos out of single JPEG

Tags: batch-processing, actions, image-processing

I had a lot of old printed photos. To quickly scan them, I scanned them four at a time like this:

[image]

(Above yellow color is actually a white color. I purposely put yellow color to distinguish from website's white background.)

Those photos does indeed have rounded corners. Also they might not be perfectly aligned. How can I batch process these JPEG files to extract four photos out of each of those JPEGs?

PS: I am new to this site and also I dont have much experience in graphics editing / designing.

Answer (score 1):

Before you try either of the following solutions, check to see if your scanner software allows for scanning multiple photos. Some have this feature built-in.

**If you have Adobe Photoshop**, it's possible using one of the built-in automation scripts. Open the image and click *File > Automate > Crop and Straighten Photos*.

or

**If you have GIMP** (which is free), something similar is available using [this script](https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2019/05_w20/1420491/DivideScannedImages.scm)*. Download it and save it in your GIMP scripts directory.

Make sure all your scanned images are in one folder, run the script from GIMP using *Filters > Batch Tools > Batch Divide Scanned images*. Choose the "Load From" and "Save to" directories, and run it.

*Note: I have no connection with the developer of this script. I have tested it however, and it works with GIMP 2.10

Comment: Just googled for the video and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEn5xEAs2JU). Seems the neat thing. Only thing is that I dont have photoshop 

Comment: @Mahesha999 Then you can use GIMP. It's free.

Comment: can we batch crop and striaghten in photoshop?

Comment: @Mahesha999 . . . Yes, you can record an action and use File > Automate > Batch.